# Call Two MySql Table with A Button

Tags: php, mysql

I have these table that list all the users of the site. I would like to add a button where in, once that is clicked, the other details of the user will show.

This is my code so far.

```
echo "<table border=1 align=center><tr class=style2><td>+<td>Student Name<td>Age<td>Address<td>School<td>Email";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT name, age, address, school, email FROM mst_user",$cn) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($query))
{
    echo "<tr class=style8><td>+<td>$row[0]<td align=center> $row[1]<td align=center>$row[2]<td align=center>$row[3]<td align=center>$row[4]";   
}
echo "</table>";
```

The code shows all the user of the site. The `<td>+`will be a button that when click will show the other details of the user. The other details will show or call a file which is `result.php`

**result.php**

```
$rs=mysql_query("select t.test_name,t.total_que,r.test_date,r.score from mst_test t, mst_result r where
t.test_id=r.test_id and r.login='$login'",$cn) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<h1 class=head1> Result </h1>";
if(mysql_num_rows($rs)<1)
{
    echo "<br><br><h1 class=head1> You have not given any quiz</h1>";
    exit;
}
echo "<table border=1 align=center><tr class=style2><td width=300>Test Name <td> Total<br> Question <td> Score";
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($rs))
{
echo "<tr class=style8><td>$row[0] <td align=center> $row[1] <td align=center> $row[3]";
}
echo "</table>";
```

my tables

[image: mst_test]
[image: mst_result]

Any suggestions on how can I achieve it?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).